# mvc ajax modal validate not being called

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple modal form (mvc / bootstrap / jquery)

in the head I have (amongst other includes)

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

the form is defined as;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="send-email">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3>Email Documents</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Recommendations", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "emailform" name="emailform"}))
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="enquiryId" name="enquiryId" />
        <span>Email Address:</span><input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" />
        <input type="submit" class="icon-envelope center">
    }
    <div id="validationSummary" class="validation-summary">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>            
    </div>
</div>
```

My validate javascript is;

```
initArticleModal = function () {
alert('in validate');
$("#emailform").validate({
    rules: {
        emailAddress: { email: true, required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        emailAddress: "Email Address is Required"
    },
    errorContainer: "#validationSummary",
    errorLabelContainer: "#validationSummary ul",
    wrapper: "li",
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        submitSendEmail($(form));                                   
    }
});
}
```

The alert triggers, so I know that I am initialising this correctly.
But when I submit, the submitSendEmail javascript is not being triggered, the forms default sumbit is. Neither is the validation, so I assumne that there is an error in my javascript, but nothing is reported in the console.

I have given the elements names as I read somewhere that that is what validate works on.

So what have I done wrong?

Comment: Place your script tags just before `</body>`. This goes with 99% of scripts (Modernizr being the general exception). This isn't the problem most likely (as unobstrive wraps the initializer in a `$(function(){ ... });`) but still good practice.

Comment: Why you are not using a tightly bound view? you could avoid all the headache of manually adding the validations.. Just create a model and add data-annotations to it rest all will be taken care by framework.

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe this form is to be called on a number of different pages, all of whom are already backed by viewmodels. Are you suggesting I add an input view model to all those viewmodels?

Comment: is this a partial view?

Comment: Yes it is. I could create an EmailFormInputModel easy enough, but as the partial is a modal popup bound to pages that list lots of customers, won't that just create lots of irrelevent objects in my IList<view model> ?

Comment: Where is the validate java script code placed? are you sure it is getting executed after the partial view is loaded?

Comment: I reworked it to use an EmailInput Model. What I didnt realise is that I can create a partial and pass in a new EmailInputModel() as a parameter. The it calls back to my code and works. thanks for the pointers to send me in teh correct direction